# How to get codeigniter URL parameter value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

my url is following:

`http://localhost:8000/business/products/category/1`

and i want to get the last **1** parameter from URL using jquery. Is there any method to do so?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will get last segment even with different number of segments:

```
$segs = $this->uri->segment_array();
echo end($segs);
```

Comment: `end($segs);` end() is PHP inbuilt.

Answer (score 2):

Using `split()` creates an array, `pop()` returns last element of array

```
alert(location.pathname.split('/').pop())/// alerts 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by splitting the URL into segment first.

Try like this

```
var segments = url.split( '/' );
var action = segments[3];
var id = segments[4];
```

You get the URL using Jquery like this

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

Comment: what about the slashes in protocol? easier to use `location.pathname` as base

Comment: Yeah. If you want to get path or url use like this `var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only  var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL`

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this by getting it from php and embedding it into the javascript:

```
var category = <?php echo $this -> uri -> uri_to_assoc()['category'] ?>;
```

**OR**
using only javascript

```
var url = window.location.href;
var idx = url.indexOf("category");
var category = url.substring(idx).split("/")[1];
```